# EF One to One Principal Relation Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have looked at other questions here, and at my other projects utilising EF but can't work out why I am getting the error when trying to create the controller with views using EF.

The message I'm getting is telling me it does not understand the principal relationship between `Company` and `PoolCar`, which is a one to one relationship.

`Unable to determine the principal end of association between the types PoolCar and Company.`

Company 1 <-> 1 PoolCar 1 <-> * CarAllocation

I've assigned the foreign key on the dependent table (PoolCar) but it's still throwing the same error.

What have I missed?

```
[Table("Company")]
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        // navigation property
        public virtual PoolCar poolCar { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("PoolCar")]
    public class PoolCar
    {
        [Key]
        public int poolCarId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("companyId")]
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public string poolCarName { get; set; }
        // navigation property
        public virtual IList<CarAllocation> carAllocations { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("CarAllocation")]
    public class CarAllocation
    {
        [Key]
        public int carAllocationId { get; set; }
        public int poolCarId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("poolCarId")]
        public PoolCar poolCar { get; set; }
        public string allocationName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have encountered this problem before and believe it may be a bug in EF. Obviously you can get round this by configuring the relationship in the fluent API, see @vinodh answer but if you insist on using data annotations then you can put the foreign key attribute on the `poolCarId` property instead.

```
[Table("PoolCar")]
public class PoolCar
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("company")]
    public int poolCarId { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public Company company { get; set; }
    public string poolCarName { get; set; }
    // navigation property
    public virtual IList<CarAllocation> carAllocations { get; set; }
}
```

It's also worth noting that your code would work if you didn't have the navigation property on the principal side of the relationship, that is, if you removed `public virtual PoolCar poolCar { get; set; }` from the `Company` model.

I do believe it is a bug as I see no reason EF can't distinguish which side is the dependent when you're explicitly declaring a foreign key.

Comment: Glad it's not just me - is this bug still here with the latest .NET? Currently using 4.2 I believe.I've played around with the lazy loading on the Company model, but I still get the same error. Not tried to use the Fluent Api before., will check it out.

Comment: it's not really anything to do with the .NET version but the version of EF. We currently use version 6 and the problem is still there. I'm not 100% sure it is a bug, they may be a very good reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

It is foreign key and Association key independent problem. So you just to make fluent mapping , we can understand the problem very clearly. Do the following in your fluent Api section.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasOptional(obj => obj.poolCar)
        .WithRequired(obj1 => obj1.company);
```

Comment: Just try this, lemme know if it is not solve , i ll give a another solution

Comment: Will have a go, let me just look into Fluent Api as I've never used it, don't know where to put it etc.

Comment: It is under the fluent Api section in your context.

Comment: You override `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext`

Comment: yes. Actually FluentApi is used for validating  our poco class.. We have annotation and fluent Api. If you use this Validation you can handle the this kind of error very well. That is why i m saying you to do this. :)